# Python3, Accessing json array value from API - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am currently struggling to consume an API for a script I'm writing, not that familiar with Python or JSON. Basically I am sending a couple of get requests and want to access a value that is held in an un-named array, but I am getting the following error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request_radius.py", line 15, in <module>
    node = jdata[0]['name']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code that I am writing is below (values have been changed). I am trying to pull out the value that is MANCHESTER, from name, which I thought would be entry 0 in the array, but  I guess I'm missing something or I need to approach this from another angle.

```
import requests
import json

LIST = ['1','2']
data = {}

for i in LIST:
    api = 'http://foo.bar.com/values/%s/nodes' % (i)
    r = requests.get(api)
    r.raise_for_status()
    jdata = r.json()

    # value returned [{'name': 'MANCHESTER'}]

    node = jdata[0]['name']
```

Thanks for looking :D

UPDATE:

API call was returning blank values, tried again when it was working as expected and was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an IndexError because jdata is empty. My guess is this is caused because your response is an empty json.

Are you sure your comment about the value returned is accurate?

Comment: You are right, the values I'm getting have not been consistent, something is not right with the API. Thanks!